# how get array data with foreach loop in this code?

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array:

```
$customer_info=[
    array(
        'name'=>array(
            'fistname'=>'jason',
            'lastname'=>'jason'
        ),
        'id'=>'1'
    ),
    array(
        'name'=>'name2',
        'id'=>'1'
    )
];
```

and I want to get firstname and lastname from this array .

Comment: There is  no _date_

Comment: Your title and your question don't really match, what date? And what foreach loop? What format is the end result supposed to be in?

Comment: Is the answer `$customer_info['name']['firstname']` ?

Comment: Are you looking for this ? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/80e569b9512138b7dde6b12a17494f9d9e9ce8b2

Comment: with foreach loop

Comment: no for example you change the one of the name to name1

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Add your expected output, this will help clarify your problem.

Comment: @Progrock the code return array instead of the value of firstname and lastname

Answer (score 0):

`array_column($customer_info, 'name')` should give you an array of all 'name' elements in your 2d array. I'll edit the answer if you can explain better what you want to do here.

If you really want to do it with a foreach loop, simply:

```
$output = [];
foreach ($customer_info as $row) {
    $output[] = $row['name']
}
```

Comment: ok but if the code like this $customer_info=[
    array(
        'name'1=>array(
            'fistname'=>'jason',
            'lastname'=>'jason'
        ),
        'id'=>'1'
    ),
    array(
        'name'=>'name2',
        'id'=>'1'
    )
];

Comment: Dear Shardj , You looks so helpful nature but your spoon-feeding help may cause  increase SO problem if future if they don't try first.

Comment: @NikleshRaut you're correct, I did flag the issue already for being unclear but no one else seems to have joined me in flagging it

Comment: @Shardj this is not my code wrote two different array name 1 and name 2 could answer it what should i do with that ?

Comment: @Shardj can you answer it ?

Answer (score 0):

Should be fairly straight-forward, but we are looping through your array, checking if 'name' is an array or a string, and handling both scenarios.

This will display the information on the page, I wasn't sure if this is what you wanted or if you wanted to store the information into an array for use later.

If you want this stored as an array, what is the format of the array you need, are you going to concatenate the first and last names or store them in a multi-dimensional array?

```
foreach($customer_info as $key => $customer) {

    if(is_array($customer['name'])) {

        echo 'First Name: ' . $customer['name']['firstname'] . '.<br />';
        echo 'Last Name: ' . $customer['name']['lastname'] . '.<br />';

    } else {

        echo 'Name is: ' . $customer['name'] . '.<br />';

    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you assuming he wants to echo the out, or that it should be html? He specifies getting an array in his title

Comment: He hasn't given much information about his desired output, I have a note about this on my post. If he provides this information I will sort this out for him, I've opted to echo the data so he can see what is happening and modify it himself.

Comment: the code return Array and i want the value of the firstname

Answer (score 0):

this should work fine:

for first array:

```
$name = $customer_info[0]['name']['fistname'];
$family = $customer_info[0]['name']['fistname'];
```

for second array:

```
$name = $customer_info[1]['name'];
```

Comment: `$name` and `$family` referencing the same array key in your example.  Did you try it?